# Area Light Rotation

Tags: animation, lighting

my tutor on you tube can be able to rotate and set area light using yellow point, however I can't. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about the yellow gizmo which lets you point the light towards a specific direction. For that to be visible you habe to make sure that you have turned on the gizmo visibility option and also the **Look At** option in that menu. One more thing, the look at option doesn't exist for point lights as they are basically just a point (more of a sphere actually) and they do not face some direction.

[image]